# Java native library architecture depend on JVM or OS?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to load native library to Java program, which is fine but I don't know which architecture should I load. If I'm running on x64 and I have a x64 JVM I will load 64 bit library but If I will run on x86 JVM on x64 what I should load ? It should be based on OS or JVM ?

Thank you

Comment: You should load the library at the same bit depthness as the JVM (x64 for x64 and x32 for x32)

Comment: Primarily, on the JVM.  An application running in 32-bit mode needs 32 bit libraries.  An application running in 64bit mode needs 64bit libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bitness" of the native library must be the same as that of the JVM.

If you are using a 32-bit JVM, you need a 32-bit native library (no matter if the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit).

If you are using a 64-bit JVM, you need a 64-bit native library.